# How I can to create array with tyoe HKEY in c++builder?

Tags: arrays, registry, c++builder

I need

```
HKEY [] all={HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, HKEY_CURRENT_USER, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, HKEY_USERS, HKEY_CURRENT_CONGIG}.
```

But in my opinion, to create array, i must use anything else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was mistake at word ConGig. Should be Config.

> HKEY [] all={HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT,
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
>   HKEY_USERS, HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG}.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are not to far of I think the following should work:

```
HKEY all[] = {HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, HKEY_CURRENT_USER, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, HKEY_USERS, HKEY_CURRENT_CONGIG};
```

Couldn't test it i'm on a Mac.

Comment: It's funny, but i'm on pc and i need to decide my problem)

Comment: Did you notice I changed HKEY [] all to HKEY all[]? The first will not compile the second will assuming all the symbols are correct. If that was not the question then make your question clearer.